# SOAP UI Netsuite TBA Authentication Issue

Tags: soap, soapui, netsuite, access-token, suitetalk

I am in the process of trying to set up an integration with our freight company to pull tracking details into Netsuite.

To familiarise myself with the process I have installed SOAP UI and created an integration on our Sandbox account.

I am simply trying to get the authentication to work to run some basic requests for information from the sandbox account.

I have run the getDataCentreUrls function and this works fine.

But when I try to run the getServerTime or indeed any function which involves authentication I get the below error:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode>
         <faultstring>An unexpected error occurred.</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <platformFaults:invalidCredentialsFault xmlns:platformFaults="urn:faults_2022_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
               <platformFaults:code>UNEXPECTED_ERROR</platformFaults:code>
               <platformFaults:message>An unexpected error occurred.</platformFaults:message>
            </platformFaults:invalidCredentialsFault>
            <ns1:hostname xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">partners128.prod-cwl-eu6.core.ns.internal</ns1:hostname>
         </detail>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Below is the code I am using to try and get the server time. It's pretty much the default code that is populated when the wsdl is imported, but with as much stripped out as possible to simplify things. I have hidden the account, consumer key and token.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:messages_2022_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:urn1="urn:core_2022_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <urn:tokenPassport>
         <urn1:account>accountnumber</urn1:account>
         <urn1:consumerKey>alongconsumerkey</urn1:consumerKey>
         <urn1:token>alongtoken</urn1:token>
      </urn:tokenPassport>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:getServerTime/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have given myself a role with the developer role which seems to have all the relevant permissions for using token authentication.

I have generated the tokens.

I have tried these basic functions but no joy.

What am I missing here?

ConsumerKey I am assuming is the ConsumerKey, when it says Token underneath does it mean the ConsumerSecret, the Token ID or the Token Secret? The tag here is a little ambiguous. Although if I am honest I have tried all the combinations.

All help greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You will have to ask those questions to your dev team. It is likely that you may have to use an encryption key.

Comment: Sadly, I am the dev team.

Comment: Who developed getServerTime ?

Comment: Oracle designers

Comment: Look in the logs on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Specific to my issue - The problem was the SoapAction header not matching the type of request I was making in the body.

Be warned, when using SoapUI or Postman if you import the request library from Netsuite you still need to dot the i's and cross the t's with things like the headers and default script parameters for the nonce, timestamp etc.